# Splash screen appears on Debug mode but not on Release (iOS4)

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios4, release, splash-screen

I have iPhone 3GS, iOS4, xcode 3.2.3.

After loading the Default.png, I add a little splash screen the looks exactly like the application start view.
This splash screen appears animating in Debug mode, but do not show at all in Release mode(I get a blank screen), this of course rules out any problems with the image, like size or name.
I have tried clean all targets, no luck, I also tried to make the release configuration to look exactly like the debug configuration (like strip debug symbols during copy and optimization level) for the sake of troubleshooting, I am going no where.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Check your copy resources build phase to see if the Default.png is in there. Perhaps it has been deleted but the phone is using a cached image (due to not cleaning your build) thus giving you false indication that it is working on Debug.

To test, fully clean all builds and run debug, or just check that Default.png is being copied over.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Solved. Thanks for coneybeare for the hints.

The problem had nothing to do with Debug or Release mode, I made a clean all only under Release but not under Debug. When I have done it for both, I got the same behavior from both modes. 
Because of the fact that the splash screen was working under Debug (before doing a clean all), I tended to overlook my code. Now, I had to look again into my code, I figured out that [window makeKeyAndVisible] was removed during previous modifications, and thus, the splash screen view was not showing.

Comment: You should delete this "answer" and put it as an update to the original question.  Then, it is common courtesy on Stack Overflow to mark the correct answer as correct (click the green check next to my answer) so that future questions asked by you will be answered faster.